# Visual Studio Code: HTML syntax highlighting not working

Tags: visual-studio-code

After reinstalling my system and VSC, I opened my project and found out that syntax highlighting [no longer works for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMqUj.png) in .html files.

What might be the issue?

Comment: all HTML is colored, you use some template engine so choose the correct languageID

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: `ctrl+P` and search for `language`

Comment: Is it 'Change Language Mode'? What should I do with it? I'm currently at 'Auto Detect'.

Comment: what template engine do you use Django, Jinja, ..... search a language definition for in the marketplace and select that as Language Mode